# phpmyadmin change default collation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever i create a db in phpmyadmin the collation gets `latin1_swedish_ci` and i have to change it to `utf8_general_ci` how can i do so that every db i create the default collation is `utf8_general_ci`?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [**Server Character Set and Collation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html), you might want to change the value of [**`collation_server`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_server) *(quoting)* :

> the server character set and collation
>   depend on the options that you use
>   when you start mysqld.
> You can use
>   `--character-set-server` for the
>   character set.
>  Along with it, you
>   can add `--collation-server` for the
>   collation.

I suppose you could also set that variable in your `my.cnf` file -- if you have write-access to it, of course.